# How does the angle of an isosceles triangle change as you increase the height

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, triangles, angle

$ABC$ and $ADB$ are isosceles triangles. Given $\beta,$ $R$ and $h$, how can I find angle $\alpha$?

- $\beta$ is the top angle of the triangle $ABC$, so $\angle{ACB}$.
- $h$ is the change in height between $ABC$ and $ADB$.
- $R$ is the length of one of the legs of the isosceles triangle $ADC$, so $\vec{|AD|}$ and $\vec{|DC|}$.
- $\alpha$ is the top angle of the triangle $ADB$, so $\angle{ADB}$

My friend and I worked on it a bit, but we found some really complicated solution that was unusable. The problem itself seems pretty simple, so I feel like we did a wrong step at one point. Any help appreciated!

Here is an image of the Isosceles Triangles better describing the problem:

[image: two isoscales triangles]

Comment: Could we see your "really complicated", "unusable" solution? Please edit it into the question for better visibility. Among other things, it would save people the trouble of writing up a solution that is no better than what you already have.

Answer (score 1):

Drop from point $C$ a line that's perpencular to $AB$ at $H$.
As the triangle is isosceles, let $HB = HA = a$. Triangle $CHB$ and $DHB$ are right triangles.

With some knowledge of trigonometry, you have:

$a = \sin(\alpha/2)R \tag1$

$(a\cot(\beta/2)+h)^2 +a^2 = R^2 \tag2$

or $a^2  (1+\cot(\beta/2)^2) +2h\cot(\beta/2)a + h^2-R^2 = 0$

This is a quadratic equation and it should be easy to solve.
Found $a$ and you can find $\alpha = 2\arcsin(a/R).$

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. I’ve tried to solve the polynomial but although I get a solution it is not quite elegant. Is this the nature of the solutions or is there some simpler form that I could get to in the end?

Comment: I would say it's the nature of the solution. I would suggest you can draw some sample by hand and measure the degree to check. Hope this helps and tbh I think there would be a more optimized solution than mine!

Answer (score 0):

Let $M$ be the middle of $AB$, so $DM\perp AB$. Then use trigonometric functions in $\triangle CMB$ and $\triangle DMB$:
$$MB=R\sin\frac\alpha2\\h+CM=R\cos\frac\alpha2\\\tan\frac\beta2=\frac{MB}{CM}$$
Get $CM$ in terms of $MB$ and $\beta$ from the last equation and replace it in the second equation. The first and second equations now contain only two variables, $MB$ and $\alpha$. Calculate $MB$ first. To do that, square the equations and add them together. Use $\sin^2\frac\alpha2+\cos^2\frac\alpha2=1$. Then get $\alpha$ from the first equation.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. I’ve tried to solve the polynomial but although I get a solution it is not quite elegant. Is this the nature of the solutions or is there some simpler form that I could get to in the end?

Comment: Would you consider$\beta = 2\arctan (\tan (\alpha/2)(1/(1-(h/(R\cos (\alpha/2))))))$ more usable? Same equations but we solve for $MB$ and $CM$ in the first two then substitute into the third and do some factoring.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is let
$\space\gamma=\dfrac{\alpha}{2}$

$\space \sin\gamma 
=
\dfrac{\dfrac{\overrightarrow{AB}}{2}}{R}
\implies \gamma=\sin^{-1}
\dfrac{\overrightarrow{AB}}{2R}
\implies 
\alpha=2\sin^{-1}
\dfrac{\overrightarrow{AB}}{2R}
$

An alternative is to let $\space g \space$ be the height from the base to point $\space C.$

Then
$\space\tan\dfrac{\beta}{2}=\dfrac{\overrightarrow{AB}}{2g}
\implies g=\dfrac{\overrightarrow{AB}}{2\tan\dfrac{\beta}{2}}$

Let $\space H=g+h \space$ which is the altitude of the larger triangle

Then
$\space\tan\dfrac{\alpha}{2}=\dfrac{\overrightarrow{AB}}{2H}
\implies \alpha=
2\tan^{-1}\bigg(
\dfrac{\overrightarrow{AB}}{2H}
\bigg)$

Comment: We are not given $g$ or $H$.

Comment: @CyclotomicField  I defined $\space g\space$ in the first  "Then" statement and I defined $\space H\space$ in the following "Let" statement.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\theta = \angle BCD = \pi - \frac\beta2$ and $\phi = \angle CBD.$
Then by the Law of Sines,

$$
\frac{\sin\phi}{h} = \frac{\sin\theta}{R} = \frac{\sin(\beta/2)}{R}.
$$
Therefore
$$
\phi = \arcsin\left(\frac hR \sin \frac\beta2\right).
$$

But also
$$ \frac\alpha2 + \phi + \theta = \pi. $$

So
\begin{align}
\alpha &= 2(\pi - \theta - \phi) \\
&= 2 \left(\pi - \left(\pi - \frac\beta2\right) - \phi\right) \\
&= 2 \left(\frac\beta2 - \phi\right) \\
&= \beta - 2\phi \\
&= \beta - 2\arcsin\left(\frac hR \sin \frac\beta2\right) \\
\end{align}